# Pandas dot-format date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I want to get a column called Datetime with entries like `28.4.2014 12:20:49` into datetime format. When I do

```
df = pd.read_csv('LOG.TXT', delim_whitespace=True, names=['Datetime', 'x'])
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
print(df['Datetime'])
```

I get `28.4.2014   2014-05-30 12:20:49`
because Pandas does not parse the dot-format. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally pandas should be able to parse this automatically, so I think something went wrong with you `read_csv`: you have a space in the datetimes, but you are also using whitespace as the delimiter, therefore it will put the date and time in different columns.

To illustrate this:

```
In [67]: s = """28.4.2014 12:20:49 1
   ....: 29.4.2014 12:20:49 2"""

In [68]: from StringIO import StringIO 

In [69]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True, names=['Datetime', 'x'])

In [70]: df
Out[70]: 
           Datetime  x
28.4.2014  12:20:49  1
29.4.2014  12:20:49  2

In [71]: df['Datetime'][0]
Out[71]: '12:20:49'

In [72]: pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'][0])
Out[72]: Timestamp('2014-05-30 12:20:49')
```

The date is set as the index, and the time is in the `Datetime` column. When converting this time with `to_datetime`, it will use the date of today.

To solve this, one possibility (I read it in as three columns, and say with `parse_dates=[['Date', 'time']]` to parse those two columns together to one datetime):

```
In [92]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True,
   ....:                 names=['Date', 'time', 'x'], parse_dates=[['Date', 'time']])

In [93]: df
Out[93]: 
            Date_time  x
0 2014-04-28 12:20:49  1
```

---

But if you have a more special format, you can always use the `format` keyword:

```
In [66]: pd.to_datetime("28.4.2014 12:20:49", format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
Out[66]: Timestamp('2014-04-28 12:20:49')
```